# Retrieving data from the table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables

1. `table1` (`id, stateId(fk), name, carId(fk)`)
2. `table2` (`stateId(pk), state, countryId(fk)`)
3. `table3` (`countryId, country, currency`)
4. `table4` (`carId, car`)

I want to retrieve name, state, country, car from the above tables through stored procedure using joins. And if some other easy way then please tell.

thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.  From your comments, it's not clear what results you want (and why).

Answer (score 0):

A simple `JOIN` should do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.YourStoredProcedureName
AS
SELECT t1.name, t2.state, t3.country, t4.car
FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.stateId = t2.stateId
    JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.countryId = t3.countryId
    JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.carId = t4.carId
GO
```

Comment: It will repeat all the rows as many times as number of countries.

Comment: @user2512996 -- what are your desired results (and perhaps sample data).  You mentioned nothing in your post about duplicated records.  What should it show for multiple countries?

Comment: ok, i have 3 countries(a,b,c) in table3 and the condition is that one id in table1 can be in only one country, also one id in table1 can be in only one state and one id in table1 can have only one car now i want to select above specified fields where id=1 in table1

Answer (score 0):

No other easy method. Join is basic and easy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select tbl1.name, tbl2.state, tbl3.country, tbl4.car
From table1 tbl1 
inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.stateid =tbl2.stateid   
inner join table3 tbl3 on tbl2.countryid = tbl3.countryid
inner join table4 tbl4 on tbl1.carId = tbl4.carId
```